# `Foreman start web` is giving me weird output and the server won't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, foreman

I wanted to begin my experience with Heroku earlier today and so far it's been really aggravating. I've been on the edge of my chair all day!

I've finally figured out all of the Postgres problems and done a `bundle install` to update everything in my RoR directory.

Now I've run `foreman start web` as I was told to do that [over at Heroku's welcome tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#run-the-app-locally). This doesn't work and my site doesn't load at localhost:3000. This is the output I have from the command:

```
MacBook-Pro:ruby-getting-started alexander$ foreman start web
/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/psych-2.0.13/lib/psych.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0014 p:-17564591312208 s:0070 e:000069 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0068 e:000067 CFUNC  :require
c:0012 p:0115 s:0064 e:000063 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0011 p:0007 s:0054 e:000053 TOP    /Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/psych-2.0.13/lib/psych.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0010 p:---- s:0052 e:000051 CFUNC  :require
c:0009 p:0115 s:0048 e:000047 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0008 p:0009 s:0038 e:000037 TOP    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:5 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0036 e:000035 CFUNC  :require
c:0006 p:0115 s:0032 e:000031 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0005 p:0063 s:0022 e:000021 TOP    /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0004 p:---- s:0020 e:000019 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0115 s:0016 e:000015 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0002 p:0090 s:0006 E:000708 EVAL   /usr/bin/foreman:13 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000818 TOP    [FINISH]

/usr/bin/foreman:13:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/psych-2.0.13/lib/psych.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /usr/bin/foreman

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb
    4 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    6 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
    9 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   10 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   11 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
   15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
   16 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   17 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
   18 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/pathname.bundle
   19 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb
   20 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/version.rb
   21 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman.rb
   22 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/helpers.rb
   23 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb
   24 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb
   25 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/procfile.rb
   26 /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/dotenv-0.11.1/lib/dotenv/substitutions/variable.rb
   27 /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/dotenv-0.11.1/lib/dotenv/substitutions/command.rb
   28 /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/dotenv-0.11.1/lib/dotenv/parser.rb
   29 /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/dotenv-0.11.1/lib/dotenv/environment.rb
   30 /usr/local/foreman/vendor/gems/dotenv-0.11.1/lib/dotenv.rb
   31 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/delegate.rb
   32 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/etc.bundle
   33 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb
   34 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb
   35 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb
   36 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb
   37 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb
   38 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine/cli.rb
   39 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/ostruct.rb
   40 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/base.rb
   41 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/inittab.rb
   42 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/util.rb
   43 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/strscan.bundle
   44 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb
   45 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/upstart.rb
   46 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/daemon.rb
   47 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/bluepill.rb
   48 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/runit.rb
   49 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/supervisord.rb
   50 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/launchd.rb
   51 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export/systemd.rb
   52 /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/export.rb
   53 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   54 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap: 6
```

Thanks for being here to help me. I have no idea what any of this is and I'm at a complete loss as to what I should do to get this site running on my local machine. Thanks.

I'm using OS 10.10.3 and Ruby 2.2.1 at the moment.

Comment: What does your Procfile look like?

Comment: It's a basic Procfile.
`web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`

Comment: It looks like you’ve mixed up your Ruby installs, there are references to the system Ruby, and to rvm installed 2.2.1. You might be able to fix it simply by installing `foreman` into the rvm Ruby (i.e. `gem install foreman`). At the moment it seems that when you run `foreman` your system is finding the version install in the system Ruby (at `/usr/bin/foreman`) and so is starting Ruby 2.0.0, but when it tries to load the Psych gem it finds the version compiled for 2.2.1. This version mismatch is likely the cause of the segfault you are getting.